# Add an external library to SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to add a library Calendar of dhtmlxScheduler to SAPUI5 but I have no idea how to use it in `view.xml`

For example, you can see the code `index.html` of dhtmlxScheduler , in the `<body onload=init();">` there are `<div>` of button, so my question is How I can do it in `view.xml`?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use a `sap.ui.core.HTML` control in your view to embed your own HTML code.

Here an example: 
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.Html/preview

Comment: Hi Rafael, thanks for your answer, my solution is to use xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" , it's the same yours

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, just use  **xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"**

[image]